# How to clear req.session.array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to display `errorMessages` to the user **once** after they fail registration. If the registration page is visited again the `errorMessages` array will not be displayed. For some reason `req.session.errorMessages` is being displayed on every request to the registration page.

```
module.exports.registration = function(req,res){

    if(Array.isArray(req.session.errorMessages) && req.session.errorMessages.length > 0)
        res.locals.errorMessages = req.session.errorMessages;
    else
        res.locals.errorMessages = [];

    res.render('registration',{

    });

    //This line does not seem to reset the array after the response has been rendered
    req.session.errorMessages = [];

};
```

Comment: Try moving it above the `render` call.

Comment: @Scimonster Thanks. Thank works. Write it as the answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it above the `render` call. It seems that you can't change `req` or `res` anymore after returning data to the user.